# What should I do about a weak project lead who never appreciates my work?

Tags: leadership, complaint

For the last half year I have been working on an automation project that requires good technical skills. As a part of this project I have trained two interns and also worked hands on by resolving functional and technical issues and writing additional subroutines wherever necessary.

I have also reviewed the code and made it much better than what we had started with. In addition I have made spreadsheets to track progress and have done literally everything a "lead" is required to do, which is : leading by example.

There is another set of interns who are being led by a very capable person in the team. This entire project however has a lead who has never contributed to it. I don't report to this person but he is in charge of this project "officially".

The general impression across the team is that this lead is ineffective, and does not seem to appreciate the hard work I put in. There have been times when he has tried to demean me by ignoring my contributions, and also keeping us in the dark when it comes to the roadmap of the project.

I had tolerated this behaviour for quite some time but now I dont want to lay low. My manager is aware of the work I do and is very appreciative. There are 2 things i want to convey to him:

1. Often this lead person has shown a demeaning attitude towards me and never shown any appreciation, verbal or non verbal.
2. He does not appear to have technical skills. To my knowledge, he has never contributed an idea, let alone a line of code.

I am not happy with his leadership at all. How do I go about conveying this? I have put in a lot of thought about this, so I do not believe I am overreacting or exaggerating.

Comment: The question, as it stands, is basically a rant.  Things like "it is known across the team that he is an airhead" is defamatory without proof.  There are no actual situations and specificity to work with.

Comment: What outcome do you want, other than telling your immediate supervisor how you feel?

Comment: Please [edit] your third paragraph. To what project does *This entire project* point to? How is the other project relevant to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you met with this lead and shared your concerns directly? It's certainly possible that the situation is exactly as you describe, but it's also possible you're not be seeing the whole picture. Perhaps the lead is busy, is on multiple projects, or has a more managerial role that doesn't involve day-to-day coding. From that perspective it may seem like he's an absentee leader.

Focus on what you are hoping to achieve. Do you want recognition for your work, or do you want reassurance that others have the same opinion of this lead? Sometimes people are not noticed for their good work because they do not promote their own successes, and expect people just to notice.

Instead of putting forth a list of grievances, try to work with your manager to improve your own situation, rather than bring down someone else for its own sake. If that involves interaction with the lead, so be it, but don't let someone else's behavior affect your own well-being.

If the lead is as bad as you say, eventually things will catch up with him.